# How to fill in a small hole in the tub?

Tags: waterproofing, tub

There is a small hole in my tub, measuring about half a centimeter at its longest dimension. It is not deep - only the white glossy finish of the tub is chipped off. What material do I use to fill in this hole such that it be waterproof?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pros used much to my surprise, bondo, at least the one I was watching. Then an air brush was used to "blend in" the color coat, an epoxy paint.[image]

This was on Ebay for 18 bucks USD. quality looks questionable though. Just showing this one as an example